# Compare a variable against more than one (an array of) variables, with the same outcome, in PHP

Tags: php, navigation

I have a simple navigation which uses php to know which "current page" you are on allowing my css to indicate this.

my php code:

```
<?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'about.php') { ?>
```

What I'm trying to do is have this button active as the current page within its child pages?
is there any way of having multiple pages within the above code?

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
<?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'about.php about2.php about3.php') { ?>
```

Comment: `if (something) { ... } else if (something_else) { ... } else { ... }`? this will quickly grow to be very ugly/unmaintainable, however.

Comment: What about an array? `if (in_array($currentPage, array('about.php', 'about2.php', 'about3.php'))) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
<?php $pages = Array("about.php","about2.php","about3.php"); ?>
<?php echo "\n"; if (in_array($currentPage,$pages)) { ?>
```

Which will basically go through an array and compare the value (`$currentPage`) with each of those in the array.

Comment: sorry im back, I have done it as above but I cant get it to work fully? if I use for example ("about.php","about2.php","about3.php") like above it only picks up the original about.php. If I use ("about.php","home.php","contact.php") they all work fine? DO i need to put some php code or something into the new pages?

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Wont work:
<?php $pages = Array("about.php","about2.php","about3.php"); ?>
Will work:
<?php $pages = Array("about.php","home.php","contact.php"); ?>

the second uses pages that already exist? does this matter?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing after the condition so, possibly.

Comment: I've put it below, any ideas? I thought I had it all right... until I tried it out :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `in_array()` function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
if (in_array($currentPage, array('about.php', 'about2.php'))) {
// Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(NOT AN ANSWER JUST AN UPDATE)

This is what I have at the moment: (only the about.php activates the switch)

```
    <?php $pages = Array("about.php","about2.php","about3.php"); ?>
        <?php echo "\n"; if (in_array($currentPage,$pages)) { ?>
            <li class="button on">
            <img src="style/images/clear.png" width="100px" height="100px" alt="clear_image" />
            About
            </li>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <li class="button off">
                <a class="nav" href="about.php">
                    <img src="style/images/clear.png" width="100px" height="100px" alt="clear_image" />
                    About
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
```

If I change the pages to home.php, contact.php (which were in the navigation originally) they all work turning them all on at the same time?
So im not sure what I need to do in order to include my new pages?

I this is one of my other buttons:

```
     <?php echo "\n"; if ($currentPage == 'contact.php') { ?>
            <li class="button on">
                <img src="style/images/clear.png" width="100px" height="100px" alt="clear_image" />
                Contact
            </li>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <li class="button off">
                <a class="nav" href="contact.php">
                    <img src="style/images/clear.png" width="100px" height="100px" alt="clear_image" />
                    Contact
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
```

Is this why it is picking up the original pages but not my new ones?

Comment: You haven't defined `$currentPage`

Comment: I have this at the top of the page: <?php $currentPage = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); ?> is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, it's because the pages don't exist. `basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);` equals the name of the page the script is running on

Comment: Really really sorry, just realised what I have been doing wrong, in short on the about.php page I had switched the navigation to one that include an extra link just for this page.............. I hadn't updated the code on this navigation with the php array... sorry, and thanks for all your time! its working like a charm! :)